# Android - Facebook SDK's ShareButton prompts to open browser after successful sharing from WebDialogs

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully implemented the Facebook SDK's `ShareButton` in my application. The `ShareButton` works perfectly when I have the official Facebook application installed. But when I don't have the official app, the `ShareButton` opens up a `WebDialog`.

**My Problem:**
Whenever I share any post using the WebDialog, It prompts to open up the browser. The post is successfully shared but still the `WebDialog` prompts to open the browser.

**Screenshot:**

1) This is the `WebDialog`

[image: This is the Webdialog]

2) This is what I get after post is shared
[image]

**Code:**

```
public class FragmentDetails extends Fragment
{
    ShareButton facebookShareButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
        facebookShareButton = (ShareButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentDetails_FacebookShare);
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .build();
        facebookShareButton.setShareContent(content);


        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @KapilRajput Shared the code.

Comment: this sounds like a bug, it should not be opening the browser after sharing.  you should file a bug report here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs ?